# Laravel collections not sorting

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections, laravel-5.3

I have the following Eloquent collection:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 60902,
        'source' => 'M',
        'price'  => 10.15
    ],
    [
        'id' => 57348,
        'source' => 'A',
        'price'  => 12.00
    ],
    [
        'id' => 54472,
        'source' => 'A',
        'price'  => 12.00
    ],
]
```

I'm trying to sort it with this code:

```
$items = $items->sort(function (Item $a, Item $b) {
    if ($a->source == 'A') {
        if ($b->source == 'M' || ($b->source == 'A' && $a->price < $b->price)) {
            return 1;
        } elseif ($b->source == 'A' && $a->price == $b->price) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        if ($b->source == 'A' || ($b->source == 'M' && $b->price < $a->price)) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($b->source == 'M' && $b->price == $a->price) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

However, the original sort order of `$items` is always the same before and after. The first item (60902) in the list should have been moved from the beginning to the end.

I ran an Xdebug trace and can see that item 60902 returned `-1` in the sorting function and the other two items returned `0` because they are equivalent to each other.

This is how I expect the collection to look after sorting:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 57348,
        'source' => 'A',
        'price'  => 12.00
    ],
    [
        'id' => 54472,
        'source' => 'A',
        'price'  => 12.00
    ],
    [
        'id' => 60902,
        'source' => 'M',
        'price'  => 10.15
    ]
]
```

Where is my logic messed up here?

Comment: what you want to do ?. sorting by price and sort in desc ?

Comment: I'm doing a complex sort by source and price. Source A preferred over source M. If same source, lower price better than higher.

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking about, but assuming you get the result from a database, why not order the result on the database query level? `ORDER BY source, price` should do it.

Comment: I simplified the results for this post. Everything after the first item is the result of a merge from other query results. The price value only comes thru a relation. This is done for efficiency due to the number of records and the rarity of needing to do this sort. Sometimes I need to call `save()` in the relation, so keeping them separate is handy. Otherwise, I'd agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was ridiculously simple...I just needed to swap `1` and `-1` when returning the sort value to get the results I wanted.

New code looks like this:

```
$items = $items->sort(function (Item $a, Item $b) {
    if ($a->source == 'A') {
        if ($b->source == 'M' || ($b->source == 'A' && $a->price < $b->price)) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($b->source == 'A' && $a->price == $b->price) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        if ($b->source == 'A' || ($b->source == 'M' && $b->price < $a->price)) {
            return 1;
        } elseif ($b->source == 'M' && $b->price == $a->price) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
});
```